# Do magnons exist in 1D?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, ferromagnetism, spin-chains

I'm confused about the state of a system described by the quantum Heisenberg model

$$ H = -J\sum_i \vec{S}_i \cdot \vec{S}_{i+1} $$

in 1 spacial dimension (1D spin chain). We can find the low energy exact eigenstates of this Hamiltonian. In the ferromagnetic case ($J>0$), they are spin waves (magnons)

$$ |\psi_k \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_n e^{i k na}\, |\uparrow,\uparrow,...,\downarrow,\uparrow,\uparrow,..\rangle_n $$

with lattice spacing $a$ and the quantum state with spin down at the nth site. The dispersion is $\epsilon_k =2J \big(1-Cos(ka) \big) $.

A fundamental principle of statistical mechanics is that the state of a quantum system in the canonical ensemble at temperature T is given by the density operator
$$ \rho=\frac{e^{-\frac{H}{k_B T}}}{Z} $$
Therefore, I conclude that for small T, the only states in this statistical mixture with large contribution are the groundstate and the magnons. If we measure properties of the system at low T, they should be determined by the magnons. Expectation values of observables are weighted expectation values of that observable in a magnon eigenstate.

Is this picture correct? Because it seems to be in conflict with the Mermin-Wagner theorem. This theorem says that the system cannot break the rotation symmetry of the Hamiltonian in 1D and thus can't have long range order. It seems to imply that the state of the system cannot be described by magnons. My professer said that there are "no spin waves in 1D".

Question: Is the Mermin-Wagner theorem in conflict with the fundamental principle of the statistical operator? Do magnons exist in the 1D chain?

Comment: Could you describe how you get from the spin-wave picture to LRO?